# Сравнение элементов массива, проверка на схожесть

Tags: php, laravel

не получается разобраться с задачей.
У меня есть вот такой массив с массивами

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 22
            [5] => 23
            [6] => 24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
            [5] => 20
            [6] => 21
            [7] => 22
            [8] => 23
            [9] => 24
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )

)
```

Задача в том, что нужно сравнить каждый элемент массива друг с другом и если есть хоть одно похожее значение записать номер массива.
Пробовал многими способами ничего не получается, нужна помощь

Comment: Какими способами вы пробавали? Добавте в вопрос попытку решения.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
$arrays = Array(
    Array(18),
    Array(7,9,10),
    Array(12,22,33,34),
    Array(7,22,4,5)
);

$repeats = "";
$all_items = array();
foreach($arrays as $var=>$val){
    $all_items = array_merge($all_items, $val);
}

foreach($arrays as $var=>$val){
    foreach($val as $subvar=>$subval){
        if(in_array($subval, $all_items) && array_count_values($all_items)[$subval] > 1){
            $repeats .= '['.$var.']['.$subvar.']<br/>';
        }
    }
}

echo $repeats;
```

На выходе получим элементы двумерного массива (можно поменять как нужно или что нужно получать: второй номер, или первый, или вместе):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]